# how do I cast field from double to float and round it using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have two dataframes with the schema as below:
books_with_10_ratings_or_more_with_title:

```
root
 |-- ISBN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
 |-- average: double (nullable = true)
```

and 
books_df:

```
root
 |-- ISBN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
 |-- average: double (nullable = true)
```

I tried to join them together and change the rating(i.e. average) to float

```
books_with_10_ratings_or_more_with_title = books_with_10_ratings_or_more.join(books_df, 'ISBN').select('ISBN', 'Book-Title', 'Book-Author', 'Year', books_with_10_ratings_or_more.average.cast(float))
```

so I can round it with the following code, it throws an error:

[unexpected type:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDS5l.jpg)

What's wrong with the code and how do I fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please update the schema for `books_df`. Please also add your (as complete as possible, including imports) code using `round`.

Answer (score 8):

You can either do

```
books_with_10_ratings_or_more.average.cast('float')
```

or

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
books_with_10_ratings_or_more.average.cast(FloatType())
```

There is [an example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=cast#pyspark.sql.Column.cast) in the official API doc

EDIT

So you tried to `cast` because `round` complained about something not being `float`. You don't have to cast, because your rounding with three digits doesn't make a difference with `FloatType` or `DoubleType`.

Your `round` won't work because you are using the function from python. You need to import it from `pyspark.sql.functions`. For example,

```
from pyspark.sql.types import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, round

df = sc.parallelize([
  Row(isbn=1, count=1, average=10.6666666),
  Row(isbn=2, count=1, average=11.1111111)
]).toDF()

df.select(round(col('average'), 3).alias('average')).collect()
```

Comment: Thank you, what I was missing is single quote in the cast. Now it's float and I verified it by checking its schema, however, when I tried to round it with `round('average',3)`, I got an error message: `a float is required`, do you know what's the reason? Thanks