# Casting double to float

Tags: casting, pyspark

I'm trying to cast a column in double type into float, so I'll be able to use the `round()` function. I tried different way to do it but it doesn't work in my case.

```
df=EAS3 

gap_AZ= (col('KPI_2') - col('average'))/col('average')*100).cast(FloatType())
    EAS3 = (EAS3.withColumn('GAP', lit(gap_AZ)))
```

I expect to have `gap_AZ` as a float type column. But when I use FloatType it forces it to STRING type.

Is anyone know what happen? 
Thank you

Comment: You can typecast the 'GAP' column to FloatType.

Comment: why are you use `lit(gap_AZ)`? UUIC, you just need to do: `EAS3.withColumn("GAP", (col('KPI_2') - col('average'))/col('average')*100).cast('float'))`

Comment: Thanks Pault,
I just wanted to kept it in a variable

I tried with your code but still have problem when i use round('GAP')

"TypeError: a float is required"

Comment: I am fairly certain that you are using `__builtin__.round` when you should be using `pyspark.sql.functions.round` - a [mcve] would have shown that. Try `import pyspark.sql.functions as f` and do `f.round("GAP")`.

Comment: You got it! Thanks very much Pault

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I cast field from double to float and round it using pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181747/how-do-i-cast-field-from-double-to-float-and-round-it-using-pyspark).

Comment: Yes it is, i didn't notice this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this UDF function:

`from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
tofloatfunc = udf(lambda x: x,FloatType())
changedTypedf = df.withColumn("Column_name", df["Column_name"].cast(FloatType()))`

Comment: Thanks Anuj, Can you explain what does tofloatfunc do?

Comment: @Benjamin6482 it does nothing in this code since it's never called.