# Python as_dict() converting decimal values 0.0 as decimal(0)

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe, which I am trying to convert into list of dictionary. For that I am doing,

`list(map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df.collect()))`

But this is converting some of the decimal values in the dataframe from `0.0` to `decimal(0)`.

Expected:

```
[{'Name': 'John','Weight': 0.0, '_id': '0010z00001aZa0RAAS'}]
```

Actual :

```
[{'Name': 'John','Weight': Decimal('0'), '_id': '0010z00001aZa0RAAS'}]
```

**EDIT**:

I need this because, I have to pass this exact list to MongoDB for storing, and PyMongo does not support `Decimal('0')` and throws error as below :

`MongoDB ERROR: data not inserted: cannot encode object: Decimal('0'), of type: <class 'decimal.Decimal'>`

Also I have tried to convert spark df to pandas df as
`json.loads(df.toPandas().T.to_json())).values()` to get the dictionary. But this approach seems to be very slow.

What am I missing ? I am new to this. Thank you for any help

Comment: Why is that a problem? Given the concept of duck typing, is there ever a time that the decimal zero does not quack the way you want?

Comment: Because I have to pass this exact list to MongoDB for storing. PyMongo does not support this.

Comment: You should probably mention that in the question, possibly with the exception that helped you discover that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Decimal objects don't quack like a float in normal usage anyway. `decimal.Decimal('0')+1.0` raises a TypeError.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica. Agreed. I just wanted to make sure that we avoid an XY problem.

Comment: @Ahalya. Are you ok with a solution that either fixes the output or makes the database input work? Or do you strongly prefer the former?

Comment: Are you missing quotes around John?

Comment: Any solution would be fine. I just need to convert from dataframe to dictionary so that I can store it into mongoDB using pyMongo @MadPhysicist

yes, sorry.. I missed the quotes. updated now

Comment: Would going through the list and just converting the value with `float()` be too slow for you?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I think so, because presently I have 50000 records and it can grow more.

Comment: It took me less than a second to run `for d in l: d['Weight'] = float(d['Weight'])` on 50000 instances.

Comment: Otherwise, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181747/how-do-i-cast-field-from-double-to-float-and-round-it-using-pyspark) might be the answer.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych this is just a sample example I gave, there are multiple such decimal fields , I cannot hardcode field names. I will have to check if value is decimal or not and all that I have to do If I use for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Ahalya,
I think you can achieve this by converting the weight to float from decimal

for  `[{'Name': 'John','Weight': 0.0, '_id': '0010z00001aZa0RAAS'}]`
here is the sample code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = ...
df = df.withColumn("weight", col("weight").cast("float"))
df_dict = list(map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df.collect()))
```

you'll get 0.0 instead of Decimal(0,0)

EDIT 1:
if you have to check for decimal columns and cast them dynamically:

```
column_schema = df.dtypes
for cols in column_schema:
    if 'decimal' in cols[1]:
        df = df.withColumn(cols[0], col(cols[0]).cast("float"))
```

Explanation:
in columns_schema you collect column_name, datatype as list(tuple(column,datatype)) from dataframe.
Later you loop dataframe with column_schema and cast columns which are of datatype decimal(0,0) to float.

I agree that this is crude way of doing, but I'm just giving you an approach, you can refine this in a better way.
Hope this helps!